# Is move elision required in case of copy list initialization in C++20?

Tags: c++, c++20, copy-elision

Please consider following C++20 program:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A() {}
    A( const A& ) = delete;
    A( A&& ) { std::cout << "m "; }
};

int main() {
    [[maybe_unused]] A a = {{A{}}};
}
```

I expected that move elision is required here according to the standard, so `A( A&& )` will not be called. Still Clang calls it: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/oobh7vWoh

Could you please clarify whether it is really permitted or not by the standard?

P.S. There is a similar question [Copy elision for list-initialization, where is it stated in the standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49535106/copy-elision-for-list-initialization-where-is-it-stated-in-the-standard) but it differs from this one by `initializer_list` constructor, so I do not think this one is a duplicate.

Comment: I am not sure if this required as the rule for initialization is `In the initialization of an object, when the initializer expression is a prvalue of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the variable type` [Link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)

Comment: @xskxzr, I am not sure because there is no initializer_list constructor in my case

Comment: How is this distinct from your recent question that I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68433046/8586227)?

Comment: That question has nothing to do with initializer_list. I answered that question with an example containing initializer_list. It is just an example.

Comment: But your example is opposite: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6G8d8oY3c from the example in this question. In this example clang calls two constructors, and in your example gcc does it.

Comment: From https://cppinsights.io/ , `A a = {{A{}}}` is understood as `A a = A{{A{}}}`. (`A a = A{A{A{}}};` doesn't use move constructor BTW [Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fno4cs1E7)).